# Importing GitHub commit data into spreadsheet file

Tags: git, github, spreadsheet, commit, feature-extraction

I need to download commit data of an open source project in an spreadsheet file. Is there any way to extract the commit data (`Commit ID`, `file changes`, `#LOC addition`, `#LOC deletion`) from GitHub to spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the repo cloned anywhere, the following git command below provides info about commit, author name/date and the stats summary of the commit. You could run the command and store the output in a CSV file.

```
git log --since='last month' --pretty=format:'%h;%an;%ad;%s' --numstat > summary.csv
```

The output should be something like:

```
69bbf3e;Firstname Last name;Tue Aug 29 11:21:19 2017 -0400;Commit headline
2       0       dir-a/file-a
```

The numbers before the file path indicate the number of additions and deletions to a file

Comment: I did clone the repo as save it in a folder; then run the command, it shows the following message  [ fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git ]

Comment: did you run the command after changing directory to the folder? The error says that you are not running the command from the top folder of the git repo

Comment: i solved the issue. but the data that extracted include only (commit ID, author, date, and summary) How can i get the number of code addition & deletion of each commit??

Comment: with `--numstat` you should get a list of files changed by each commit with the number of additions and deletions (see amended answer above)

Comment: I used the command; it successfully extract commit log and save it in csv file. But the only concern is the format of the log doesn't help for automatic lookup of a specific value (like number of additions). Is there a way to make the log well-structured in row and column?